# SSIS get top N records from an aggregation in data flow

Tags: ssis, aggregate

I have a data flow where i group the records using the aggregate control.
Each group has a category and a record count.

Now id just like to take the categories with the top 10 highest counts and store them in a database.

except for looping through them in a scrip component and inserting them into a table there is there another way to do this..ie through a component which grabs the top 10.  something like percentage sampling.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Sort transformation` after the `aggregate transformation` . After that use `Row Sampling transformation` to get your Top N rows.

***Update:***

If it is not working with the Row Sampling transformation'. just replace this transformation with 'Script transformation'. In which we could generate the RowNumber. After that we could use the conditional split transformation with condition RowNumber<=10. so that we could filter the rows.

Steps:

1. Add `Script component` and select it as "`transformation`"
2. Create the column as follows to store `RowNumber` as per following screenshot.
3. Add these into the ***code base***.
4. Add `Conditional Split transformation` and have condition like RowNumber<=10

[image]

So, Now only top 10 rows will be selected

Code:

```
//variable to store row number   
private int counter


//Add this method, which is automatically called once.
public void New()
{
    counter = 0;
}

//Edit the following to increment the counter
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    counter += 1;

    Row.RowNumber = counter;

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sampliing seems to selects the top 10 rows randomly.  Even thouth the the random seed option is NOT selected.  Data viewers show data is correc and in the correct order when it hits the sampling control but then it chosed 10 random records

Comment: Yes i did use a transformtion script but ended up creating code which reads the the first 10 rows and passes them through the buffer.  Once 10 have gone through no more records go to the output buffer, So only 10 records came out the other end.  But thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you removed your Row sampling transform?

Comment: Yes. I do an aggregate and select the first 10 it creates sort on value I'm after and then pass to the script.

Answer (score 0):

I'd dump the aggregate data out to a table & use T-SQL RANK() to get the top 10.